# How to use a for loop to insert multiple records in a database table

Tags: php, sql, database, loops

I have simplified my problem into the following code:

```
$sql_abc = "CREATE TABLE $tbl_abc(
    x INTEGER(255)
)
";

echo "About to execute $sql_abc";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_abc)) {
    echo "Table $sql_abccreated successfully<br>";
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>";
}

for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $sql_abc = "INSERT INTO $tbl_abc VALUES ($x)";
}

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql_abc)) {
        echo "New records created successfully<br>";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql_abc. "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
```

I am trying to get 10 records in the table, with each incrementing by one in the 'x' field.

However, all I see is:

[image: Here is what I see]

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: you need to put the actual insert statement in the for loop, so each time it increments the `$x` it should also execute the insert statement as well, right now the loop completes it's iterations and the insert statement only executes for the last value of `$x` because your insert statement is after the for loop

Comment: Could you please suggest an edit to the code to fix it? Is ```$sql_abc = "INSERT INTO $tbl_abc VALUES ($x)";``` not currently in the ```for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++)``` loop? Thank you!

Comment: please share complete code so I can fix it for you. Show where you execute the `"INSERT INTO $tbl_abc VALUES ($x)"` query string ?

Comment: Done, I've added it to the post. Thank you.

Comment: A good practice will be to handle connection error only once when you first make the db connection, you don't need to check the connection every time you execute a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do that.

```
for ($x = 1; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    
    $sql_abc = "INSERT INTO $tbl_abc VALUES ($x)";

    //this query will execute for each value of $x
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql_abc);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm only starting out with php now and am unfamiliar with how to execute the queries!

Comment: No worries, Just search about the best way to handle db connections and learn best coding practices. Have a good day.